# How do I extract the text from the html tag and how do I filter the text that it contains?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

So What I am trying to do is grab the text from the particular tag within the link and what I want to do is return the html only if the text contains certain words for example: if text contains "chemical" then return that link if not pass

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)
base_url = 'https://ca.indeed.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
rcontent = r.content
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "html.parser")

all_job_url = []

def get_all_joblinks():
    for tag in prettify.find_all('a', {'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"}):
        link = tag['href']
        all_job_url.append(link)

def filter_links():

    for eachurl in all_job_url:
        rurl = requests.get(base_url + eachurl)
        content = rurl.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        summary = soup.find('td', {'class':'snip'}).get_text()
        print(summary)

def search_job():

    while True:

        if prettify.select('div.no_results'):
            print("no job matches found")
            break
        else:
            # opens the web page of job search if entries are found
            website = webbrowser.open_new(url);
            break

get_all_joblinks()
filter_links()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be getting all the links from a single indeed.ca page in your `get_all_joblinks` function. Here's how you could check whether a typical link mentions 'chemical' somewhere in the text in its `body` element.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('https://jobs.sanofi.us/job/-/-/507/4895612?utm_source=indeed.com&utm_campaign=sanofi%20sem%20campaign&utm_medium=job_aggregator&utm_content=paid_search&ss=paid').content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> body = soup.find('body').text
>>> chemical_present = body.lower().find('chemical')>-1
>>> chemical_present
True
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Edit, in response to comment.

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> job_type = 'engineer'
>>> location = 'Toronto'
>>> url = "https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + job_type + "&l=" + location
>>> base_url = '%s://%s' % parse.urlparse(url)[0:2]
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> for link in soup.find_all('a', {'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"}):
...     job_page = requests.get(base_url+link['href']).content
...     job_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(job_page, 'lxml')
...     body = job_soup.find('body').text
...     if body.lower().find('chemical')>-1:
...         webbrowser.open(base_url+link['href'])
```

Comment: yeah I want to extract all the links and then filter them out based on certain text they contain. After they are filtered I want to display the link with the filtered ones. Is that possible?

Comment: Please see edit. I should perhaps warn you that this code takes a long time to run.